# After override hashCode, toString() return the same value for the same object but after using "==" return false

Tags: java, string, reference, tostring, hashcode

As you may know Object has some function,
For example we have toString() from oracle Documentacion we can know by default it's return HexValue of hashCode() 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()
We also can use hashCode() for checking of equality object (of course implementation depends on you)
So I made implementation for my Class Projekt :

```
public class Projekt {

    int i;
    public Projekt(int i) {
        this.i=i;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + i;
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Test Code:

```
Projekt projekt = new Projekt(1);
System.out.println(projekt.toString());
System.out.println(projekt.toString() == projekt.toString());
```

Output:

```
Projekt@20
false
```

Also i try to inside value from projekt.toString() in StringPool by writing:

```
    String string = projekt.toString();
    String stringABC = projekt.toString();
    System.out.println(string == stringABC);
```

According to PoolString i should have the same reference but outPrint is false.

So this method return different reference value but i can't understand why?

Comment: Why would you expect these two strings to be the same object?

Comment: `==` returning false *means* that it *isn't* the same object.

Comment: I copied this from diffrent comenatry: But to save memory we're using StringPool. If we have the same value, refereance is also the same it's working just for creating String not by constructor. If i had String s = new String("a"); String s2 = new String("a"); I used 2 space in memory, but when i use String s = "a"; String s2 = "a" I use 1 space in memory. So that's mean toString() return "new String()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> I copied this from diffrent comenatry: But to save memory we're using StringPool. If we have the same value, refereance is also the same it's working just for creating `String` not by constructor. If i had `String s = new String("a"); String s2 = new String("a");` I used 2 space in memory, but when i use `String s = "a"; String s2 = "a"` I use 1 space in memory. So that's mean `toString()` return "new String()"?

Your source should have said:

> ...it's working just for creating `String` using string literals.

That way it might have been clearer, because there are many ways to create new `String` objects without directly calling the constructor. String literals are those things surrounded by `"` (including the quotes), such as `"a"` or `"b"` or `"Welcome to Stack Overflow"`.

Only string literals<sup>1</sup> are pooled automatically. You can manually put a string into the pool by calling `intern()`.

When you concatenate two strings (e.g. `stringA + stringB`), a new string is generally created, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1).

Now let's look at what [`Object.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) does:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Note that strings are being concatenated here, so a new string object is being created here, hence the output.

And to answer the question of:

> So that's mean `toString()` return "new String()"?

Yes, but not directly. The compiler will turn the `+` operators in `Object.toString` into some code using `StringBuilder` (or rather, "the compiler *has turned*..." since the `Object` class has already been compiled). At the end, it will call `StringBuilder.toString`, and that will create a new `String` object.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Constant expressions of strings, to be more accurate.</sub>

Comment: That was something what i want to know, the others comments say me the same what i wrote but using diffrent describe. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "toString()" method **returns** a string. So everytime you call `toString()` it returns a new reference because Strings are immutable (even if they're the same text)

Comment: String string = "a";
String string2 = "a";
System.out.println(string == string2); output: true. because here the referenace is the same cause String using StringPool. this is my way to understand, please make me correct if i was wrong.

Comment: Yes but the toString() method is a little bit different and @Sweeper explained why.

Answer (score 0):

String class is just a pointer to string (char) data somewhere in the memory. It is a class, it is not a primitive type like boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float and double.

So, comparing two strings you compare pointers.

You generate two strings in:

```
String string = projekt.toString();
String stringABC = projekt.toString();
```

So you have 2 different pointers now. They have the same text inside, but they are in different places in memory.

But you can use equals() method of object:

```
System.out.println(string.equals(stringABC));
```

Comment: But to save memory we're using StringPool. If we have the same value, refereance is also the same it's working just for creating String not by constructor. If i had String s = new String("a"); String s2 = new String("a"); I used 2 space in memory, but when i use String s = "a"; String s2 = "a" I use 1 space in memory. So that's mean toString() return "new String()"?